# classification via RBF by matlab

Tags: matlab, classification

I want to classify 16 different data in 3 categories by RBF in matlab. I wrote this code but I think it doesn't work correctly for new data.

```
Inp=[1 2 .1 2 .2 3 .1 1.5 .5 1.6 2 2.5 3 3 3.5 3.5;
 .1 .2 .3 .3 .4 .4 .5 .5 .6 .7 .6 .7 .6 .75 .8 .55];

Out=[1 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0;
  0 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0;
  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1];
figure(1); hold on
 for itt=1:length(Inp)
   if Out(1,itt)==1
     plot(Inp(1,itt),Inp(2,itt),'ro','MarkerFace','r','MarkerSize',10);
   elseif Out(2,itt)==1
     plot(Inp(1,itt),Inp(2,itt),'k^','MarkerFace','g','MarkerSize',10);
   elseif Out(3,itt)==1
    plot(Inp(1,itt),Inp(2,itt),'bs','MarkerFace','c','MarkerSize',10);
   end
end

xlim([0 4])
ylim([0 1])
text(.5,.5,'Fighter')
text(3.5,.1,'Bomber')
text(3.5,.9,'Passenger')
 net=newrb(Inp,Out)
```

for example

```
B=[1;.1]
C=sim(net,B)
C =
1.0000
0.0000
-0.0000
```

and it train correctly but for this new input can not classify right

```
B=[3.5;.1]
C=sim(net,B)
C =

6.2763
0.2457
-5.5220
```

while I think it should answer like before and classify in Bomber category. Please help me.

Comment: Don't you need to normalize the data (input/output) of the network?

Comment: @NKN How normalize the data ?

Comment: As I see in your case the data always have to be in range `[0 1]`. Check for instance this post: https://machinelearning1.wordpress.com/2014/07/13/linear-vector-mapping-scaling-matlab/